# unable to fetch results using returning into clause for cursors of record type

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, cursor

I have a procedure which should return 3 dept names and update the start time for these three dept names. This script will be run by parallel threads.
I tried to achieve it using cursors but not returning the result.

Table with inserts:

```
create table dept (sno number(4), deptname  varchar2(40), start_time date)
insert into dept values(1,'DEPT1',NULL);
insert into dept values(1,'DEPT2',NULL);
insert into dept values(1,'DEPT3',NULL);
insert into dept values(2,'DEPT4',NULL);
insert into dept values(2,'DEPT5',NULL);
insert into dept values(2,'DEPT6',NULL);
```

### Approach 1:

```
TYPE    deptname        IS RECORD(op_deptname     dept.deptname%TYPE);
TYPE    cursor_deptname IS REF CURSOR RETURN deptname;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_deptname(ip_sno IN  dept.sno%TYPE, op_cursor OUT cursor_deptname);
IS
vv_dept_name dept.deptname%type;
BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE dept IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    OPEN op_cursor FOR
        SELECT deptname
        FROM   dept
        WHERE  sno         =  ip_sno
        AND    start_time  IS NULL
        AND    ROWNUM      <= 3;
    LOOP
    FETCH op_cursor INTO vv_dept_name;
    EXIT WHEN op_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        UPDATE dept
        SET    start_time  = sysdate
        WHERE  deptname  = vv_dept_name;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF op_cursor%ISOPEN THEN CLOSE op_cursor; END IF;
END;
```

Proc execution from application.

```
DECLARE
   i         deptname;
   c_cursor  cursor_deptname;
BEGIN
     get_deptname(2,c_cursor);
     LOOP
     FETCH  c_cursor  INTO i; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('name:'||i.op_deptname);
     EXIT WHEN  c_cursor %NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

With this approach I'm able to update the table with date but dept names are not retrieved in the cursor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. If it doesn't, work on it until you feel like it is easy to read and understand. This will increase your chances of someone actually answering your question by a lot!

Comment: `op_cursor` is a ref cursor, but `returning bulk collect into` is for populating collections.

Comment: Is there any other alternate to achieve this ? I tried RETURNING INTO as well, but even that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood the question.

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from tdept;

       SNO DEPTNAME                                 START_TIME
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
         1 DEPT1
         1 DEPT2
         1 DEPT3
         2 DEPT4
         2 DEPT5
         2 DEPT6

6 rows selected.
```

The procedure, which

- updates the table
- returns refcursor

---

```
SQL> create or replace procedure get_deptname
  2    (ip_sno in tdept.sno%type,
  3     op_cursor out sys_refcursor
  4    )
  5  is
  6  begin
  7    update tdept t set
  8      t.start_time = sysdate
  9      where t.sno = ip_sno;
 10
 11    open op_cursor for
 12      select deptname
 13      from tdept
 14      where sno = ip_sno;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Execution & the result:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> var lout refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec get_deptname(2, :lout);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tdept;

       SNO DEPTNAME                                 START_TIME
---------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------
         1 DEPT1
         1 DEPT2
         1 DEPT3
         2 DEPT4                                    10.04.2018 20:32:23
         2 DEPT5                                    10.04.2018 20:32:23
         2 DEPT6                                    10.04.2018 20:32:23

6 rows selected.

SQL> print lout

DEPTNAME
----------------------------------------
DEPT4
DEPT5
DEPT6

SQL>
```

Comment: When I try to return deptname from my application, it is not returning any value.
DECLARE
   i         deptname;
   c_cursor  cursor_deptname;
BEGIN
     get_deptname(2,c_cursor);
     LOOP
     FETCH  c_cursor  INTO i; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('name:'||i.op_deptname);
     EXIT WHEN  c_cursor %NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
END;

Comment: Please, edit your initial message, remove everything you DON'T use and post only code that is currently in use. It is difficult to guess what might be wrong without seeing what you have.